# How do I print field collection's fields horizontally?

Tags: theming, entities

I have a custom node module in which there is one field collection which includes 5 other fields, and I implement hook_theme to define a custom template to theme this specific node form. In the custom template file I add "print drupal_render_children($form);" and it prints the field collection's field. How do I print the individual fields horizontally??

Comment: Can't you just customize the css for these form fields?

Comment: thank you. css for divs wrapping the individual fields only in the template file works.

Comment: Although it is possible to style field collection forms with css, I would like to have it themable with a tpl.php so that I have more control on the output. Isn't there any way to do that currently?